# Is there a way to install Groovy Eclipse e4.24 from the Eclipse update site for repast simphony, other than the springsource.org link?

Tags: groovy, repast-simphony

I am attempting to install Repast Simphony via the Eclipse update site method per https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install. When I get to step #3, I get an error saying the URL could not be found, which prevents the installation of Eclipse Groovy Development Tools.

When I try to access https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.24 through the Eclipse Update Manager per step #3 of the instructions from the repast site (https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install), I get an error saying the URL could not be found, instead of a list of available software including Eclipse Groovy Development Tools. I also tried accessing this URL directly in my browser just to see what might come up, and neither it nor the main domain springsource.org is coming up (says site cannot be reached). It looks like the site is down. Is there another way to access Groovy Eclipse e4.24 so that I can get Eclipse Groovy Development Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like groovy eclipse changed where the update site is located. I think you can find that release here:

https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/plugins-release/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-integration/4.7.0/e4.24

Nick

Comment: Thanks! However, when trying to use this link in the same way as the old springsource.org one, I am getting an error message in Eclipse saying "Error reading update site" with the URL as well as details saying "The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed." Is this resulting from the contents of the XML files at the new link? If so, do you have suggestions about how to resolve?

Comment: I updated the link -- try that one. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Looks like that worked successfully. I installed the Groovy Eclipse e4.24 's Eclipse Groovy Development Tools and 3.0 compilers. Please note that I received a security warning for these that was essentially what your instructions at https://repast.github.io/download.html#update-site-install listed for Repast. This might be due to the new site for the Eclipse Groovy Dev Tools and 3.0 compilers.